# Is there a linear injection $ \Lambda^k V^* \otimes \Lambda^k V^* \to \Lambda^k (V^* \otimes V^*)$ which preserves decomposability?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space, and let $2 \le k \le n-2$.

**Definitions**

1. We say an element $\omega \in \Lambda^k V$ is **decomposable** if $\omega=\alpha_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_k$, for some $\alpha_i \in V$. We say $\omega$ is a **power** if $\omega=\alpha \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in V$.
2. We say an element $h \in \Lambda^k V^* \otimes \Lambda^k V^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda^k V,\Lambda^k V^*)$ is a **power** if $h=\Lambda^k g$ for some linear map $g:V \to V^*$. Here, $\Lambda^k g:\Lambda^k V \to \Lambda^k V^*$ is the induced map on exterior powers, that is
   $$ \Lambda^k g(v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k)=g(v_1) \wedge \dots \wedge g(v_k).$$

> **Question:**
>   Is there a linear injection
>   $$ \Lambda^k V^* \otimes \Lambda^k V^* \to \Lambda^k (V^* \otimes V^*)$$
>   which maps **power elements** to **decomposable elements**?
>
> Even better, is there an injection which maps **power elements** to **power elements**?

**Note:** For [dimensional reasons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600991/is-it-true-that-binomnk2-le-binomn2k), there is always **some** linear embedding of $\Lambda^k V^* \otimes \Lambda^k V^*$ in $ \Lambda^k (V^* \otimes V^*)$.

**Motivation:**

This question arose in the context of applying the Plucker relations, to characterise which metrics on exterior powers are induced by metrics at the base. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290418/which-metrics-on-exterior-power-are-induced-from-metrics-on-the-base).

Comment: I think this is equivalent to $e_k\left[e_1^2\right] - e_k^2$ being Schur-positive, where the $e_i$ are the elementary symmetric functions and the brackets mean plethysm. But this is false for $k = 2$: In fact, $e_2\left[e_1^2\right] - e_2^2 = -s_{1,1,1,1} + s_{2,1,1} - s_{2,2} + 2s_{3,1}$. (Though I have ignored your $2 \leq k \leq n-2$ condition. Maybe it changes things -- although I don't expect it to.)

Comment: "Schur-positive" means "an $\mathbb{N}$-linear combination of Schur functions". Plethysm... that's a longer story. See Chapter 7 (and its Appendix 2) in Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics* (volume 2). Anyway, the main thrust of the argument is that $\Lambda^2 \left(V \otimes V\right)$, as an $\operatorname{GL}\left(V\right)$-representation, contains the irreducible subrepresentation corresponding to the partition $\left(2,2\right)$ one less time than $\Lambda^2 V \otimes \Lambda^2 V$ does (when $\dim V \geq 2$), and ...

Comment: ... thus there is no injective $\operatorname{GL}\left(V\right)$-representation homomorphism from the latter to the former. You can probably check this by hand, painful as it will be. Start by proving that the character of $\Lambda^2 \left(V\otimes V\right)$ is $2s_{2,1,1} + 2s_{3,1}$.

Comment: By the way: I am more used to seeing $\bigwedge^k V$ (`\bigwedge^k V`) than $\Lambda^k V$ (`\Lambda^k V`), but perhaps notations differ.

Comment: @darijgrinberg After some further thought, I phrased more carefully the properties I want the injection to satisfy (preserving the "power-structure" or at least decomposability. You can see my edit). I am actually not sure what kind of "natural" injections have you meant to rule out with your argument. Can you elaborate on that? (For dimensional reasons, there is always *some* linear embedding). Thanks again for your time.

Comment: darij’s argument rules out an embedding which does not depend on a choice of coordinates, or equivalently which is equivariant with respect to the automorphism group of $V$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! So it is not clear this answers the current version of the question (regarding "preserving power or decomposability"), right? BTW, I am not sure if this requirement could be satisfied, even if we allow for non-equivariant maps.

Comment: What @QiaochuYuan said. I am afraid I have no ideas about the new version of the question.

Comment: In the definition of a power element: isn't $\alpha\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha=0$ in the exterior power?